# Attach two different arrays which can have same ID's but different values?

Tags: php

**Array-1**
ID Name
1 ABC
2 DEF
3 GHI
4 PQR
5 XYZ

**Array2**
ID Names
1 abc
3 ghi
5 xyz

**RESULT**
ID  NAMES     names
1   ABC       abc
2   DEF       --
3   GHI       ghi
4   PQR       --
5   XYZ       xyz

Comment: Please elaborate on your result: Is this a data structure, web output, whatever?

Comment: It will be web out put in table with three different columns

Answer (score 1):

Question is not very clear but probably you want this:

```
$a=array("1" => "A", "2" => "B", "3" => "C", "4" => "D");
$b=array("1" => "a", "2" => "a", "3" => "a");
$ab = array();
foreach($a as $key => $value) {
   $ab[$key] = array($a[$key], $b[$key]);
}
print_r($ab);
```

**UPDATE:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => a
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => a
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
            [1] => a
        )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => D
        [1] => 
    )
)
```

Comment: I need to add one more column in result array and in that column I am printing only the names which has been differ from the first array with same key value

Comment: Can you pls tell me how're you storing array1 and array2 in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

for two arrays $a and $b

```
$n = max(count($a), count($b))
for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) {
    echo "$i\t";
    echo ! empty($a[$i]) ? $a[$i] : '';
    echo "\t";
    echo ! empty($b[$i]) ? $b[$i] : '';
    echo "\n";
}
```

edit, or if you want to create a new array "ret"

```
$ret = array();
$n = max(count($a), count($b))
for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) {
    $ret[] = array(
        "id" => $i,
        "a" => ! empty($a[$i]) ? $a[$i] : '',
        "b" => ! empty($b[$i]) ? $b[$i] : ''
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem in solutions:

- isn't there any possibility that Array-1 is missing some keys of Array-2 ?

So i suggest a little more complex solution:

```
$array_out = array();
$all_keys = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($array1), array_keys($array2)));

foreach($all_keys as $key)
{
    $array_out[$key] = array(

           'UPPER' => array_key_exists($key, $array1) ? $array1[$key] : null, 
           'lower' => array_key_exists($key, $array2) ? $array2[$key] : null
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes, array 2 might not have the same keys as array 1.

Comment: I just saw you need it to output to HTML. This just puts the arrays together, you will need to go throught the result array and output the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<nada nada>
<body>
<nada nada>
<table>
<?php
foreach ($array1 as $k=>$v) {
  $vv=isset($array2[$k])?$array2[$k]:'--';
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $k; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $v; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $vv; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
<nada nada>
</body></html>
```